# Как в HTML Purifier разрешить определенный html комментарий?

Tags: html

Как в `HTML Purifier` разрешить определенный html комментарий? Дело в том, что я использую визуальный редактор и `purifier` в связке, комментарий `<!-- pagebreak -->` он не пропускает.

Чтение доков пока мне не помогло, разрешите мою проблему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<!-- pagebreak **--**> может так?

Comment: да так я опечатался

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,2963

Comment: Там нашел директиву HTML.Trusted ,с ней работает ,но как я понял она полностью разрешает комментарии ,как разрешить только <!-- pagebreak -->